# Masked scrollable button list

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to implement scrollable button list which are displayed inside popup. I would need some kind of masking, but buttons should also work inside mask. Any suggestions how to do it?

[image: masked scrollable list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this with [CCMask](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15890) class but this is pretty slow way to do it as mask has to be applied every update.

If you use this class you will also loose button detection so you will have to play with touch detection. You will also nead a lot of tweaks to position mask & objects exactly where you want.

When you will finish everything it will not be as good as you thought it will be .. The feeling of scrolling will just not be OK, since there will be masking lag ...

It is better to hide hidden parts of scrollable items with some kind of "window" images